# Cannot Install Intercom.io gem Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install intercom.io into my rails app, however I get this when generating the config file:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/intercom-rails-0.2.14/lib/intercom-rails/config.rb:13:in `send': undefined method `define_singleton_method' for IntercomRails::Config:Class (NoMethodError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/intercom-rails-0.2.14/lib/intercom-rails/config.rb:13:in `config_reader'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/intercom-rails-0.2.14/lib/intercom-rails/config.rb:8:in `config_accessor'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/intercom-rails-0.2.14/lib/intercom-rails/config.rb:74
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/intercom-rails-0.2.14/lib/intercom-rails.rb:9:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/intercom-rails-0.2.14/lib/intercom-rails.rb:9
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/ian/SB/config/application.rb:7
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Comment: Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on ruby 1.8, and our gem currently uses a ruby 1.9 feature [Object#define_singleton_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/define_singleton_method)

We've created an issue on the [intercom/intercom-rails github repo](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-rails/issues/30) to track fixing this. I'll let you know when there's a new version.

If possible, [it's recommended to run rails 3+ on ruby >= 1.9.3](http://rubyonrails.org/download) (which for us at least mean't installing from source).

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: New version of gem released https://rubygems.org/gems/intercom-rails fixes this. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Cool! I integrated the code in the footer instead of the gem though.